# Adding image to navigation bar of tab based application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have tab base application 
I want to add logo to the navigation bar I tried

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // add image

  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
  self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;

}

but no image be displayed any suggestion to solve that

best regards

Comment: Please check whether this helps :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28212994/8013132

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting frame of `UIImageView *imageView` ...

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(myX,myY,muWidth,myHeight)
```

Let me know if you still struggle ...

Comment: the same issue, I need to add title too

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your `leftBarButtonItem` set? In the docs it says for `titleView` property of `UINavigationItem`: This property is ignored if `leftBarButtonItem` is not nil.

Comment: SO can I add background image

Comment: You should be able to if you don't have leftBarButtonItem set. Try with a a UILabel first, then with a UIImageView.